# Chrome extensions: Using chrome.tabs and chrome.contextMenus

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to create a chrome extension that scrubs a URL and opens the URL in a new tab. However I keep getting the same error as [this (content_script error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936534/chrome-tabs-is-not-supported). I've followed instructions, but I believe I just don't understand where I'm going wrong. Here is the full code:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Link scrub",  
  "description": "Removes redirectors from links", 
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs"],
  "background_page" : "background.html"
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js" : ["linkscrub.js"]
  }];
}
```

**linkscrub.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title" : "Link Trap",
    "type" : "normal",
    "contexts" : ["link"],
    "onclick" : modifyLink
});
 function modifyLink(info, tab) {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({
        "nurl" = info.linkURL,
        function(response) {
            console.log("linkscrub failed: " + response.farewell)
            }
    });
}
```

**background.html**

```
<script>
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    link = "";
    link = sender.nurl;
    link = link.match("url=\b(.*?)&link");
    chrome.tabs.create({
        "url": link,
        "selected" : false
    });
    if(chrome.extension.lastError) 
        sendResponse({farewell : chrome.extension.lastError.message});
    else
        sendResponse({farewell : "Success")};    
  });
<script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It throws error because you cannot use `chrome.contextMenus.*` API inside a content script.

You don't need a content script for this task, just move everything from `linkscrub.js` into your background page (also you won't be needing those requests).